# Unable to display a Component as Grid View in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gridview

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectData } from "../features/dataSlice";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import styled from "styled-components";
import style from "../style.css";

function Product() {
  const products = useSelector(selectData);
  const renderproducts = products.map((product) => {
    //const { id, title, price, description, category, image, rating } = product;

    return <ProductCard data={product} />;
  });

  return (
    <Container>
      <div>{renderproducts}</div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Product;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
`;
-------------------------------------

import React from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

function ProductCard(props) {
  const { data } = props;
  return (
    <Container>
      <img src={data.image} />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default ProductCard;

const Container = styled.div`
  

  padding-top: 60px;

  img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  

  img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }

  
`;
```

I need to display all the images from the products array which Iam fetching from an API as Grid View. Above is the code for the ProductCard.js & Product.js components. I have tried to add the grid view styling in the ProductCard component also. But it just does'nt display as Grid. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use grid-like.
     <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {products.map((p,i)=>( <Grid key={i} item xs={8}>
          < ProductCard/>
         </Grid>)
        }
        </Grid>
     </Grid>

for more details, you can check https://mui.com/components/grid/
```